# Keep list position using onBackPressed

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app that displays a list of news articles then takes the user to the full activity when clicked on. The list is quite long so I wanted it to keep its position when the user clicks to and from an article.

I've used `onBackPressed` in the `NewsItemActivity` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code for MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView newsListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.newsFeedList);
    adapter = new NewsListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_news_list, newsListData, this);

    newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClicked);

    EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();

  //  String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getList.php";

  //  JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);

   // app.requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);

    nextStart = 0;
    updateListData(nextStart, 20);
}

public int nextStart = 0;

public void updateListData(int StartPoint, int count){
    String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getList.php?start=" + StartPoint + "&count=" + count;

    EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);
    app.requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);

    nextStart +=count;
   // updateListData(true, nextStart, 20);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("newsItemId", newsListData.get(position).recordId);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

and for `NewsItemActivity.java`

```
public class NewsItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declare java object for the UI elements
    private TextView itemTitle;
    private TextView itemDate;
    private TextView itemContent;
    private NetworkImageView itemImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_item);

        itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        itemDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
        itemContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemContent);
        itemImage = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int itemId = intent.getIntExtra("newsItemId", 0);

        String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getItem.php?id="+itemId;

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, listener, errorListener);

        app.requestQueue.add(request);
    };

    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse (JSONObject response){

            //Put the json data in a java object
            NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
            try {
                record.recordId = response.getInt("record_id");
                record.title = response.getString("title");
                record.date = response.getString("date");
                record.shortInfo = response.getString("short_info");
                record.contents = response.getString("contents");
                record.imageUrl = response.getString("image_url");
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //show the data
            itemTitle.setText(record.title);
            itemDate.setText(record.date);
            itemContent.setText(record.contents);
            itemImage.setImageUrl(record.imageUrl, EDANewsApp.getInstance().imageLoader);
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //There was an error in the communication
            //We can notify the user about it
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your android manifest file for checking activity attribute over there

Comment: When you return back, Is your list refresh or what ?? please elaborate
from here what I see, your code is fine and should work

Answer (score -1):

You can use onSaveInstanceState( Bundle bundle ) to save the position when 
leaving your list activity.

Then you can check the bundle ( not null, contains ) for the postion in the
onCreate. Use setSelection(int) on the listview to reset the position.

```
/**
 * Save state on rotation or minimization.
 *
 * @param bundle saved values
 */
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.putInt(LAST_SELECTED, lastSelected);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

In onCreate

```
    // Check that savedInstanceState is not NULL before referencing
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(LAST_SELECTED)) {
        lastSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt(LAST_SELECTED);
    }
```

Comment: OnSavedinstance won't be called when we are navigating from one activity to other because OnSavedInstanceState is only called when activity is about to kill. Please refer the Android Documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: He is trying to maintain a position in a list. The position is self maintaining unless the activity is killed.  If the position is lost because the activity was stopped then this should cover it. If the activity has not been stopped then the postion will still be set and nothing needs to be done.